# Pass url parameter to Django ModelForm without rendering it as input on form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a url `/<subject_id>/comments/new/` which renders a Django `ModelForm`. I am using a view class derived from `FormView` to process the form. I wish to do the following:

1. `subject_id` should not appear on the rendered form.
2. `subject_id` should be added to the form prior to `is_valid()` being called, or if this is not possible should be added to the `Comment` instance.

forms/comment_form.py:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

views.py:

```
class CommentCreate(FormView):
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Do some stuff to the validated Comment instance
        # Maybe save the comment, maybe not
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How do I do this? If I add `subject_id` as a field in `CommentForm` then it appears on the rendered form. If I don't then the form is instantiated with subject_id present from `self.kwargs['subject_id'] and complains of an "unexpected keyword argument".

Comment: what is your model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hunting around in the docs I have discovered that the correct answer is to use the `get_form()` method to pre-populate the form with the data that I don't want to appear on the form, but that needs to be present for validation.

```
class CommentCreate(FormView):
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_form(self):
        self.subject= get_object_or_404(Subject, id=self.kwargs['subject_id'])
        partial_comment = Comment(user=self.request.user, subject=self.subject)
        form = CommentForm(**self.get_form_kwargs(), instance=partial_comment)
        return form
```

Comment: The line `form = CommentForm(**self.get_form_kwargs(), instance=partial_comment)` can cause problems by redeclaring `instance`. You may need to _update_ `**self.get_form_kwargs()` instead of adding it to the instantiation of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `subject_id` from form fields:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

And add it to new comment object in `form_valid` method like this:

```
class OrderCreate(FormView):
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subject_id = self.kwargs['subject_id']
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=subject_id)  
        form.instance.subject_id = subject
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I get the error: 'CommentForm' has no field named 'subject'.

Comment: @Tintin this code shouldn't raise the error. Problem is somewhere else. Can you post template and full traceback?

Comment: The error is being throw by the Comment.clean() which references Subject. I need to populate the form data with subject_id before is_valid() is called.

Comment: @Tintin ok, can you post full traceback and template also?